# NextAuth Credentials with Typescript

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I'm trying to use NextAuth Credentials with Typescript, but it's always showing a type error like this, I just copied the example from the document but cannot run it properly:
Here is the code from `/pages/auth/[...nextauth].ts`

```
return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'Credentials',
        credentials: {
          email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
          password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          const { email, password } = credentials as { email: string; password: string; };
          const { user } = await loginUser({ email, password });
          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }
          return user;
        },
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      session({ session, token, user }) {
        return session;
      },
      async jwt({ token }) {
        return token;
      },
    },
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  });
```

the `authorize` function always show this type checking error:
[image]

```
Type '(credentials: Record<"email" | "password", string> | undefined, res: Pick<RequestInternal, "query" | "body" | "headers" | "method">) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<"email" | "password", string> | undefined, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "query" | "body" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<User | null>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<User | null>'.
    Type 'Promise<User | null>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<User | null>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = User | null, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: User | null) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = User | null, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: User | null) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type 'import("/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index").User | null' is not assignable to type 'import("/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/types").User | null'.
                Type 'import("/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index").User' is not assignable to type 'import("/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/types").User'.
                  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
                    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
credentials.d.ts(13, 5): The expected type comes from property 'authorize' which is declared here on type 'UserCredentialsConfig<{ email: { label: string; type: string; }; password: { label: string; type: string; }; }>'
```

I added this type definition to `types/next-auth.d.ts`

```
import 'next-auth';
import { User as UserModel } from '@prisma/client';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface User extends UserModel {}

  interface Session {
    user: User;
    expires: string;
  }
}
```

but the error is still there

Here is `loginUser` function

```
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs';

import prisma from '@/libs/prisma';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';
import { UserLoginData } from '@/types/auth';

export const LoginUser = async ({
  email,
  password,
}: UserLoginData): Promise<{
  user: User | null;
  error: Error | null;
}> => {
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });

  if (!user) {
    return {
      user: null,
      error: new Error(`User with email: ${email} does not exist.`),
    };
  }

  const isValid = password && user.password && (await compare(password, user.password));

  if (!isValid) {
    return {
      user,
      error: new Error('Invalid password.'),
    };
  }

  return { user, error: null };
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out because in my Prisma Schema, I declared the `id` field with the type `number` and the `id` field from "next-auth" is `string`, so I need to extends the interface from the core and added the `id` definition as `number` to match my prisma schema and it works now!

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from 'next-auth';
import { User as UserModel } from '@prisma/client';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface User extends UserModel {
    id: number; // <- here it is
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh god, this was exactly the fix I needed. I was literally going insane. You're a life saver

Comment: WTH is this -__-

Answer (score 4):

This is a shorter version of the solution by @Hai Nguyen, and it works too.

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface User {
    id: number; // <- here it is
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error while using typescript, just changed the route file to .js and voila! no more errors. TS has a stricter rule for defining and using functions.
Using "next-auth": "^4.24.4" and "next": "13.4".